# Invalid token specifier in angular unit test file while running test?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `angular component` named `appointment` in which i am writing `unit-test` in `appointment.component.ts`. Below is the code of that component's test file

`appointment.component.spec.ts`

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTPService, HelperService, DataService } from '../../../services';

import { AppointmentComponent } from './appointment.component';
import { CancelApptDialogComponent } from '../cancel-appt-dialog/cancel-appt-dialog.component';
import { UpdateApptDialogComponent } from 'app/modules/app-components/update-appt-dialog/update-appt- 
dialog.component';
import { ReminderItemComponent } from './../reminder-item/reminder-item.component';

import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/autocomplete';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
import { NgxMaskModule } from 'ngx-mask';

import { CookieModule, CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { ToastrModule, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

import { DialogService } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { DynamicDialogRef } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { DynamicDialogConfig } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';

import { SharedModule } from './../../shared/shared.module';


describe('AppointmentComponent', () => {
 let component: AppointmentComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppointmentComponent>;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [
      AppointmentComponent, 
      CancelApptDialogComponent, 
      UpdateApptDialogComponent,
      ReminderItemComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AutoCompleteModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterTestingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HTTPService,
    HelperService,
    DataService,
    DialogService,
    DynamicDialogRef,
    DynamicDialogConfig,
    CookieService,
    ToastrService,
   ]
 })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppointmentComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
});

 it('should create appointment comp', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });

});
```

When i run test so it throws an error like this

```
InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified
```

[image]

What's causing this error ?

Comment: try to mock your providers u just need to verify units. Therefore mock all providers (services)

Comment: All these providers are working in another test files. And also you can see that i am not using these providers in my test file. I just included these providers to just fulfill the dependency injections.

Comment: As a best practice, u need to mock all external dependencies which are not tested here. Specially in unit tests. And If those services are unwanted just exclude those

Comment: @PushpikaWan so problem is this that my component is using different services as a `dependency` so if i remove those `service` `imports` form my `component.spec.ts` file so it start giving me `dependency injections` error. How can i solve that error?

Comment: I added it as an answer check that out. just do It and comment errors what u got.

Answer (score 0):

Just mock ur services like below. These are not the same services u added, take this as an example and do the things in ur code like that

```
 const dialogServiceSpy = createSpyObj<DialogService>(['open']);
  const dialogRefSpy = createSpyObj<MatDialogRef<any>>(['close']);
 .........................

 providers: [ 
        { provide: DialogService, useValue: dialogServiceSpy },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogRefSpy },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
        ]
```

provide all wanted services like that an remove unwanted services there.

Comment: so should i add these lines in my `component.spec.ts` file and comment out those `DialogService`, `DynamicDialogRef` imports ?

Comment: like wise u need to do this for allservices, this  just an example

Comment: i didn't get you clearly. Can you please edit my whole code and post in your answer so that i can get idea of what you are trying to say exactly and how can i do that.

Comment: Also i am not using `MatDialog` so why you included that in your answer? just want to clarify your point